# What kind of Javascript design pattern / approach is it?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Just see the code and tell me what kind of Javascript approach is it?

```
var Arithmetic = function(){
  var obj = {
    add: function(a,b) { return a + b; },
    multiply: function(a,b) { return a * b; }
  };
  return obj;
}();

var resultAdd = Arithmetic.add(a,b);
var resultMul = Arithmetic.multiply(a,b);
```

Why people write the js code in this way....any advantage is there for writing such way.

The above code is related to any design pattern? If yes then tell me the name.

I always write the code like this way and it is easy to understand.

```
function add(a,b)
{
return a+b;
}

function multiply(a,b)
{
return a*b;
}
```

and i just call it like this way

```
var x=add(2,3);
var y=multiply(5,8);
```

also tell me what is the disadvantage of writing code my way.

Comment: Check this out: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: Which part are you asking about? Having methods of an object like `Arithmetic.add()` instead of `add()`? Or having a function expression that is immediately executed with the result assigned to a variable like `var Arithmetic = function() {...}();`? Or all of the above?

Comment: why negative marking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disadvantage to writing code your way is that you put lots of stuff in the global namespace. Imagine what happens when you add your code that defines the add and multiply methods that work on numbers and then include a library that deals with Vectors which also defines the add and multiply methods, but which work on vectors. The methods defined last will overwrite the ones previously defined, breaking some of the code that relies on them.

For this reason, it is preferable to not pollute the global scope and when you have functionality you wish to make available, make it available via a namespace (`Arithmetic.add()` instead of `add()`).

If you analize the code a bit, `var obj` is defined not in the global scope, but in the scope of an anonymous function, so code outside of it can use the `obj` name for a variable without clashing. The functionality (two methods) is exported to public use by returning an object with the two properties from the anonymous function. Since there is no need for more than one instance of the two methods, the anonymous function returns immediately (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Another advantage to this pattern is that it allows to have private variables:

```
var uniqueId = function() {
  var id = 0;
  return function() { return id++; }
}();

uniqueId(); // 0
uniqueId(); // 1
```

In the example above there is no way to accidentally corrupt the uniqueId function to give bad (non-unique) results because you expose just the functional interface you want, instead of the whole mechanism.

Consider the equivalent in your style:

```
var id = 0;
function uniqueId() { return id++; };

uniqueId(); // 0
id = 0;
uniqueId(); // 0
```

Comment: In the example that was given by the OP, is there any advantage of creating the object inside that closure instead of just writing it down literally? I see your point in YOUR example of course, but there are no private members in `Arithmetic`...

Comment: @JohannesH. No, functionally it is the same as `var Arithmetic = { add : function() { /*...*/ } , multiply : function() { /*...*/ } }`. However, if the code should change and have parts of the Arithmetic package that are not public, it would be necessary to use an IIFE to keep things private.

Answer (score -2):

The code you gave us is an advanced example of Object Oriented code. I don'r really see the advantage of that encapuslated `obj` right now, that just makes things difficult to read.
Basically `Arithmetic` acts as a static class. Without that encapsulated `obj` and the self-executing function, it may be written like that:

```
var Arithmetic = {
    add:       function(a,b) { return a + b; },
    multiply:  function(a,b) { return a * b; }
}
```

The code you gave us really does the same - it just doesn't write down that object directly but creates it using that self-executing function (that is a closure, a "function without name", that is called (by adding `()` to it) immediately after it is created).

The advantage of OO code is not really easy to bring down in a few lines, but regarding to static classes as a collection of methods (as it's done here): it's encapusulation.You can treat each  class/object you create as a blackbox and don't have to worry about the details (once it works of course).

The disadvantqage of your "traditional" approach is: It get's corweded once you got many, many functions, and you cannot easily tell which "group" they belong to unless you include thst in your naming conventions (like `math_add()` or `math_mul()`)

Comment: _... every time you call Arithmetic_? It is not a function, nor is it a class. It is a plain object.

Comment: @amadeus: I missed the `()` at the end of the declaration of `Arithmetic`. Corrected that already - you may remove your downvote ;)

Comment: H: The IIFE-pattern is not an object oriented pattern at all.

Comment: @amadeus: Right. But the usage of `Arithmetic`, which resembels a static class with member functions, is. In the example given by Tibos in his response, you're right: no classes/objects/whatsoever there. But in the example given by the OP, `Arithmetic` is a class. The onstrcutor is a IIFE, but that doesn't change too much ;)

Comment: _'that is a closure, "a function without a name"...'_ - Whether or not a function has a name is not related to the concept of closures.

Comment: @JohannesH: JavaScript does not use classes, static or not.

Comment: It does. They are just not called classes, but prototypes. And yes, they work differently. But they serve the same purpose. I have to admit, I wasn't that precise with terms in my answer, because the OP clealry lacks the knowledge to understand them. Instead of forcing him to google every second word, I tried to describe what'S going on, using words he may already be familliar with. Not sure why this is a bad thing.